# CiviReports issue with boolean fields

Tags: civireport

I recently noticed that boolean fields (Deceased, Do Not Email, Do Not SMS, etc) are all displayed as "Yes" on contact and membership reports, regardless of their actual values. The data itself is correct and is fine elsewhere, such as in search results and contact displays. The issue seems to be only on report display. The report filters work correctly on those fields, only the display is wrong. I checked my production system, my dev system, and the public demo system at wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org and I see the same thing.

My system is CiviCRM 5.2.2, WordPress 4.9.6, PHP 7.1.16, MySQL 5.7.21.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this.  It sounds like a bug to me.  I suggest that you report it on the Issue Tracker. See https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting

Comment: Will do. One additional detail... I tried the Drupal demo site at CiviHosting and I don't see this issue. Perhaps it's related to WordPress.

Comment: Already fixed! https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/report/issues/4

Comment: Fantastic!  Would you like to answer your own question in case other people have the same problem?

Comment: Good point! I should have done that instead of commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already fixed! See: [CiviReports issue with boolean fields](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/report/issues/4)